# Lost COC base .... Need help

Tags: clash-of-clans

So here's the problem - I have 3 COC accounts on 3 devices (iPhone 4 and 2 iPads). All use different Apple IDs. My main base is on the iPhone and it always said welcome back 'username' - which I assumed meant it was linked to that Game Center account. So I was out the other day and our clan was warring - I logged out of my account and signed in on one of my other accounts (Note: I have never done this before but I figured it'd be alright since all three were under different Apple IDs and linked to their respective game centers). Once I signed out of the second account and logged back in under my main account, it did not give me the option to load my main base back in. Even though it still shows my Game Center as my main account, it loads the base from the other accounts. I am lost! I've spent 2 years on my main account and it is a high level TH10. Can anyone give me guidance on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use one of the other Apple Devices, you can log into your main account, and it should load your main base. If this doesn't work, follow the advice given by [Supercell Support](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?s=lost-village&f=i-lost-my-village-how-do-i-get-it-back&p=web).

> Using the Village available on your device, answer "NO" to "Was this helpful?" (it's at the bottom of this FAQ) Then, contact us with the following details:
>
> Please be sure to include the following information:
>
> 1. Exact Username and Clan Name of your lost Village (or player tag if possible)
> 2. Exact Town Hall level of your lost Village
> 3. Exact XP level of your lost Village
> 4. Explain how you lost the Village 
>
> For security reasons, we may need to reply with additional questions.